# The remote copy of database has not been rolled forward to a point in time that is encompassed in the local copy of the database log

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, distributed-databases

Can someone help me with the issue I'm dealing with? I had to force failover from my primary datacenter to my secondary datacenter and I forgot to disable the log backup job. Meanwhile the new secondary servers were shut down for a couple of times because of switch update. The new changes on the database weren't committed on them but log backup job in the primary date center server started and the log file was reused without acknowledgment from the secondary nodes! In the result the database in the secondary server became unhealthy. I have no idea how the log file was reused without acknowledgment! Can you help me with this?

I checked the the error logs on all servers and I got this error The remote copy of database has not been rolled forward to a point in time that is encompassed in the local copy of the database log

**I wasn't expecting the log file to be reused without acknowledgment from the second server.
log file was reused without acknowledgment from the secondary nodes
The remote copy of database has not been rolled forward to a point in time that is encompassed in the local copy of the database log**

Comment: Cross-post from [so] please migrate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76746943/the-remote-copy-of-database-has-not-been-rolled-forward-to-a-point-in-time-that

Answer (score 2):

> I had to force failover from my primary datacenter to my secondary datacenter and I forgot to disable the log backup job.

Forcing a failover will cause the log scan to be paused for all replicas. While connectivity may stay between the replicas, changes will not be sent from the primary to any secondary replicas. This means that, even if the job ran, it wouldn't do anything. Unless, of course, you resumed data movement on them which would start a new scan... but the OP doesn't say that this occurred.

> he new changes on the database weren't committed on them but log backup job in the primary date center server started and the log file was reused without acknowledgment from the secondary nodes!

The first part is correct, as I previously stated, the log scan is stopped after the force failover so no changes are being sent to any secondary replicas. The second part is not possible as the log will be held up with the `AVAILABILITY_REPLICA` reason. If this wasn't the case, then something else has occurred that is not in the OP.

> The remote copy of database has not been rolled forward to a point in time that is encompassed in the local copy of the database log

This doesn't mean the log was overwritten, it means there are no recovery forks which are common between the replicas which is expected if the replicas have not be synchronizing for some time or there were multiple events between synchronization.

This can be cleaned up by removing the secondary database replica from the AG, which will put it into a restoring state, then using log backups from the primary to bring it up to date, assuming you want to do this.